# Who gets access to Instagrams API? Devil is in the details of their statement

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

It seemed tricky trying to get someone at instagram to answer some questions so maybe you guys could help.

Heres what instagram said about API Access.

The Instagram API Platform can be used to build non-automated, authentic, high-quality apps and services that:

```
1. Help individuals share their own content with 3rd party apps.
2. Help brands and advertisers understand, manage their audience and media rights.
3. Help broadcasters and publishers discover content, get digital rights to media, and share media with proper attribution.
```

So looking at number 2.

So which of these would I be allowed to do?

Does this mean that it is permissible for me to

Use the api to find specific influencers that i would like to reach out to?

Does it mean that i need to make something that gives the influencers ore information about their demographic?

Does it mean that i could make an application which allows users to find influencers and see more info on their demographic?

I assume 3 is allowed but my question is 1 allowed as well. Do I need to make apps to be used for the public or can I use the data for only one brand?

Lastly what are a list of the information per user that the api offers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found this [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/)

"To help brands and advertisers understand and manage their audience and digital media rights: basic, public_content, comments, relationships, likes, follower_list

This use case is meant for products that don't have a public facing login integration, but are gated to brands and advertisers. The product must support either multiple brands and advertisers (e.g. a social media management platform) or multiple users within a single brand or advertiser organization."

Answer (score -1):

you can do with  this link :

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-‌​ID&redirect_uri=REDI‌RECT-URI&response_ty‌pe=code
```

replace your clinet id to your clinet-id

And replace your redirect url to your redirect url